# Listview with alphabetical sorting

Tags: android, sorting, listview

Any idea on how to make a `listview` with a `alpabetical` sorting like in music application. I wanted to make an application that have a `listview` that looks like the screen-shot below. i want the user to go or the view to be sorted alphabetically

[image]

Comment: Just sort the list/array backing the `Adapter` with the standard Java sorting methods. What problems are you having, exactly?

Comment: i know how to sort but the problem is with the design i wanted it to be like in a default music application like what ive shown in the picture

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oyR6.png)  @MikeM.

Comment: So, your question has nothing to do with sorting, though you mention it in both the title and body? What are you asking about, then? The indexer on the right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the same image you linked in the question. By itself, it doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: yes sir that was it. i was searching for it but doesnt find anything

Comment: View my answer, I think it should help ya.

Comment: Search for "index"/"indexer", not "sorting": https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bandroid%5d%20ListView%20alphabet%20indexer, https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+android+ListView+alphabetical+indexer

Comment: thank you im sorry for giving the wrong idea

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort the ListView I suggest you to sort the list that you are passing to ListView and to do that use

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to access the music store on the device, it's actually very easy. There is a ContentProvider you can access to retrive media such as videos, photos and music. Really, content providers just lay ontop of a SQLite DB, thus meaning you can access the media based on alphabetical ordering from a-Z or Z-a. I've made a Youtube [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POIRcr_bszg) detailing how to do such a thing and I've uploaded the code to Github for anyone to [peruse](https://github.com/jonndavis1993/Android-Tutorials/tree/master/MusicLoaderExample). If you wanna directly view the code, here's a [link](https://github.com/jonndavis1993/Android-Tutorials/blob/f3d89ffb55004a83daec4003c5bb09d796666aa8/MusicLoaderExample/app/src/main/java/com/simpleware/jonathan/musicloaderexample/MusicLoader.java#L29) to help ya out.

If you don't wanna load media such as photo, videos, or music you will more than likely have to manually sort the dataset you want to display inside of the ListView. If it's a simple string list, you can use [Collection.sort](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E))(list, [String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)). If it's not a simple string list, the sorting algorithm can get very complex and would definitely go beyond the scope of this answer. But if you are again, retrieving something from a database, you can have the results returned in the correct ordering based on some value, or column.

Comment: I am having more of a problem with the view or the layout itself not with the loading of dataset to the adapter. I would like to make it look like with the indexer of aphabet on the right to sort alphabetically

Comment: The picker on the side doesn't actually sort the data it simply acts as a helper for jumping to a certain index in your dataset. The data is already sorted by the time it's displayed... Let me reiterate, selecting one of the letters simply causes the listview to jump to the first item in its dataset starting with the selected letter.

Comment: @A.Bantero, your question doesn't what you've described you really want.